# forget "look in" entry in "find in files"

Tags: visual-studio-2012

once upon a time I accidentally entered my search pattern into the "look in" field in visual studio 2012's "find in files". vs has remembered this accidental location, and seems to have set it somewhere. is there a way to clear it from the list?